# How to display the server time inside Vim

Tags: vim

I want to know how to display the server time inside the Vim editor, if possible.

Comment: What is “sever time”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute external commands in Vim by using the '!' flag:

```
:! date
```

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442419-vim-tips-working-with-external-commands

Comment: As an added bonus, adding a `r` after the `:` will write the output into your buffer. Like so, `:r! date`.

Answer (score 6):

If you like, you can set Vim up so it displays the time on the status bar by adding the following lines to your vimrc file:

```
set ruler
set rulerformat=%55(%{strftime('%a\ %b\ %e\ %I:%M\ %p')}\ %5l,%-6(%c%V%)\ %P%)
```

Credit goes to **[this Vim Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_date-and-time_on_status_line)**.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i like simple as kce's answer ^^